# bootstrap modal different height in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The height of modal elements has different height in Firefox and Chrome

```
 <div class="modal fade test1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="myModalTest">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="q"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg timer" id="timer">20</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" id="continue">Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Firefox the height of `.modal-dialog` is 419px and `.modal-content` is 417px (with border 1px).

In chrome `.modal-dialog` is 459px and `.modal-content` is 457px (with border 1px).

Setting `max-height` doesn't help, as `.modal-footer` gets out of the modal.

https://jsfiddle.net/qLcopxsb/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle so i can take a look at the actual problem ?

Comment: can you provide a live demo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qLcopxsb/